# Apps Script: UrlShortener.newUrl().setLongUrl() no longer working

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code (directly copied from the UrlShortener documentation page on the Google Apps Script site) stopped working for me on the 17th June (when updates were made).

```
var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl()
  .setLongUrl("http://example.com");
var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
```

In this instance, toShorten has been returning "undefined".

Comment: Yes. It has changed. See this [related answer][1].  


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196047/has-the-url-shortener-in-google-apps-script-changed/17196595#17196595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The UrlShortner APi has changed. Make this small change to your code.

```
var toShorten = UrlShortener.newUrl();
toShorten.setLongUrl("http://example.com");
var shortened = UrlShortener.Url.insert(toShorten);
```

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17196047/has-the-url-shortener-in-google-apps-script-changed/17196595#17196595) which talks about exactly the same problem